# Gradle - Exclude dependency from War and create zip file of exculded dependencies

Tags: gradle

I have a application which have lot of dependencies and I want to reduce war footprint. I want to exclude these dependencies and create a .zip file of dependencies and I also want to know where to place this zip file so that when deployed to tomcat it can be picked up properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare the dependencies in the [compileOnly](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies) configuration so that they are not packed inside the war.

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'a:a:1.0'
    compileOnly 'b:b:2.0'
}
```

Then you could create an uber jar from the `compileOnly` configuration

```
task uberJar(type: Jar) {
    configurations.compileOnly.files.each { File jar ->
        from zipTree(jar)
    }
    classifier = 'uber'
}
artifacts {
    archives uberJar
}
```

Then you could copy the uber jar to `%TOMCAT_HOME%/lib`

Comment: It excluded the dependency but did not restrict gradle from packaging dependencies in war file

Comment: I make it out work. It was issue of bootrepackage. I am know able to create war but jar file has embed tomcat which is of different version. When I put the jar in $tomcat/libs folder `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.B2CConverter.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V` occurs. How can I exclude embed tomcat?

Comment: Why do you need tomcat in your compile time dependencies? Only reason I can think of is for testing. In this case tomcat dependencies should be declared in `testCompile` or `testRuntime` configuration